# C# XDocument get a attribute from a specific element

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, nodes

I have a problem where im trying to read a specific attribute from a element, but i just can't get the value out of it. The value im trying to get is thumb="boxart/thumb/original/front/2-1.jpg" from this element:

```
<boxart side="front" width="1525" height="2160" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/front/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/front/2-1.jpg</boxart>
```

XML:

```
<Data>
  <baseImgUrl>http://thegamesdb.net/banners/</baseImgUrl>
  <Game>
    <id>2</id>
    <GameTitle>Crysis</GameTitle>
     <PlatformId>1</PlatformId>
     <Platform>PC</Platform>
     <ReleaseDate>11/13/2007</ReleaseDate>
     <Overview>
     From the makers of Far Cry, Crysis offers FPS fans the best-looking, most highly-        evolving gameplay, requiring the player to use adaptive tactics and total customization of    weapons and armor to survive in dynamic, hostile environments including Zero-G. Earth, 2019. A team of US scientists makes a frightening discovery on an island in the South China Sea. All contact with the team is lost when the North Korean Government quickly seals off the area. The United States responds by dispatching an elite team of Delta Force Operators to recon the situation. As tension rises between the two nations, a massive alien ship reveals itself in the middle of the island. The ship generates an immense force sphere that freezes a vast portion of the island and drastically alters the global weather system. Now the US and North Korea must join forces to battle the alien menace. With hope rapidly fading, you must fight epic battles through tropical jungle, frozen landscapes, and finally into the heart of the alien ship itself for the ultimate Zero G showdown.
    </Overview>
<ESRB>M - Mature</ESRB>
<Genres>
<genre>Shooter</genre>
</Genres>
<Players>4+</Players>
<Co-op>No</Co-op>
<Youtube>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3vO01xQ-DM</Youtube>
<Publisher>Electronic Arts</Publisher>
<Developer>Crytek</Developer>
<Rating>8.1111</Rating>
<Images>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-1.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-1.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-2.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-2.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-3.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-3.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-4.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-4.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-5.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-5.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-6.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-6.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <boxart side="back" width="1525" height="2162" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/back/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/back/2-1.jpg</boxart>
  <boxart side="front" width="1525" height="2160" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/front/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/front/2-1.jpg</boxart>
  <banner width="760" height="140">graphical/2-g2.jpg</banner>
  <banner width="760" height="140">graphical/2-g3.jpg</banner>
  <screenshot>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">screenshots/2-1.jpg</original>
    <thumb>screenshots/thumb/2-1.jpg</thumb>
  </screenshot>
  <clearlogo width="400" height="95">clearlogo/2.png</clearlogo>
</Images>
</Game>
</Data>
```

Here is my code im using to read the xml with:

```
var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var gameData = feedXml.Root.Descendants("Game").Select(x => new GetGame
            {
                ID = (int)x.Element("id"),
                GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle"),
                Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform"),
                ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate"),
                Overview = (string)x.Element("Overview"),
                ESRB = (string)x.Element("ESRB"),
                BoxArt = new Uri((string)x.Element("boxart")), // This is where i would like to read the image thumb from.
            })
              .ToList();
            foreach (var item in gameData) GetGameItems.Add(item);
```

I hope there is someone that can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it can get a bit verbose, I suggest defining a new method:

```
private static string GetBoxArt(XElement gameNode)
{
    return (string)gameNode.Descendants("boxart")
                           .FirstOrDefault(b => (string)b.Attribute("side") == "front");
}
```

Then using:

```
BoxArt = new Uri(GetBoxArt(x)),
```

within your original code.

And here's a method you can use to get a comma-separated list of all the genres:

```
private static string GetGenres(XElement gameNode)
{
   return string.Join(", ", gameNode.Descendants("genre").Select(g => (string)g));
}
```

Comment: Do you know why .FirstOrDefault makes it slower than .First?

Comment: I'd imagine that `FirstOrDefault` involves a tiny bit more processing than `First`, because it has to do extra stuff, bit I would think that most of the time it would be far too miniscule to have a noticeable effect. Are you sure that there's a difference? If your data is loading at the same speed but it's just the images that seem to be slower, then that definitely has nothing to do with `FirstOrDefault` vs. `First`.

Comment: Its just the image, but its not too much. By the way, if i would like to show all genres elements, do i have to place them in a list first?

Comment: I tryed this to get the multiple genre elements to show in a textblock: public List<string> Genre { get; set; } and this Genre = (from i in x.Descendants("genre")
                                           select i.Value).ToList<string>(), but the textblock is showing code instead.

Comment: What you have there should work. What do you mean when you say it's "showing code"? What does it look like? Could you give this a try: `Genre = x.Descendants("genre").Select(x => (string)x).ToList(),`.

Comment: Thank you for using your time to help :). The textblock writes this: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: When i try this: `Genre = x.Descendants("genre").Select(x => (string)x).ToList()`, it also shows this in the textblock: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `Genre` list is being populated fine and the problem lies in how you are using that to fill your textblock. If you just assign `Genre` to the textblock, it will show up as `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]` no matter what the list contains. I recommend you open up a new question to ask about that new issue.

Comment: Hey again. I just wanted to let you know that i fixed the problem by doing this: `Genre = GetGenre(x),` and then: `private static string GetGenre(XElement gameNode)
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            foreach (string i in gameNode.Descendants("genre"))
            {
                data += i + ", ";
            }
            return data;
        }` the only thing thats not correct, is that this adds a comma to the end of the text.

Comment: I've added a more concise implementation for `GetGenre` in my answer above, and it solves the issue with the extra comma at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's two box arts, you need to tell in the query which one you need. For instance, if you want to retrieve the front box art:

```
var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

var gameData = feedXml.Root.Descendants("Game").Select(x => new GetGame
{
    ID = (int)x.Element("id"),
    GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle"),
    Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform"),
    ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate"),
    Overview = (string)x.Element("Overview"),
    ESRB = (string)x.Element("ESRB"),
    BoxArt = new Uri((string)x.Element("Images").Elements("boxart").First(e => (string)e.Attribute("side") == "front").Attribute("thumb")),
})
  .ToList();
foreach (var item in gameData) GetGameItems.Add(item);
```

Comment: When i try this, i get this error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: By the way. Do you know how i can check if the elements exists. For example the boxart front element doesn't always exist, and when it dont my app crashes.

Comment: @Thunder Then I suggest going with JLRishe's answer: move this specific code to a method, use `FistOrDefault` instead of `First`, and check whether the result is null

Comment: Yeah that works fine. But can you tell me why the images load a little slower if i use JLRishe's method?

Comment: @Thunder I don't know. If your code is correctly written, it shouldn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

'boxart' elements are children of 'Images' were 'GameTile' etc are children of 'Game'. It looks like your trying to get boxart from the game when you ought to get them from 'Images'.

Checkout your 'x' member.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the thumb attributes of boxart element like this:

```
var attributes = feedXml.Descendants("boxart").Attributes().ToList().Where(attribute => attribute.Name.LocalName.Equals("thumb")).ToList();
```